# Error message not displaying Scala Play Forms

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to get an error message to display on my form when two passwords do not match on a registration page.

Here is my form

```
  private val userRegistrationForm =
    Form(mapping("id" -> optional(of[Long]), "firstName" -> text, "lastName" -> text,
      "phoneNumber" -> nonEmptyText, "emailAddress" -> email,
      "passwords" -> tuple(
        "password" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 7),
        "confirmPassword" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 7)).verifying(
          "Passwords don't match", password => password._1 == password._2).transform[String](
          password => password._1,
          password => ("", "")
      ))(user.apply _)(user.unapply _))
```

and here is my controller where I am binding the form from a request

```
  def submit = Action { implicit request =>
    Logger.info("Submit method in Landing Page controller")

    policyHolderRegistrationForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        BadRequest(views.html.masterpage(registrationPageTitle)(registrationPageMeta)
            (views.html.policyHolderRegistration(formWithErrors, "There was an error on your form")))
      }, policyHolder => {
        policyHolderDAOActor ! PolicyHolderDAO.Create(policyHolder)
        Ok(views.html.masterpage("Home")("Home page for SuredBits")(views.html.home()))
      })
  }
```

and finally here is the template

```
@helper.inputText(field=policyHolderRegistrationForm("firstName"), 'id ->"firstName", 
'name->"emailAddress", 'placeHolder -> "First Name", '_label -> None, 'required -> "true", 
  '_showConstraints -> false
)

@helper.inputText(field=userRegistrationForm("lastName"), 'id ->"lastName", 
'name->"lastName", 'placeHolder -> "Last Name", '_label -> None, 'required -> "true", 
  '_showConstraints -> false
)

@helper.inputText(field=userRegistrationForm("phoneNumber"), 'id ->"phoneNumber", 
'name->"phoneNumber", 'placeHolder -> "Phone Number", '_label -> None, 'required -> "true", 
  '_showConstraints -> false
)

@helper.inputText(field=userRegistrationForm("emailAddress"), 'id ->"emailAddress", 
'name->"emailAddress", 'placeHolder -> "Email Address", '_label -> None, 'required -> "true",  
  '_showConstraints -> false
)


@helper.inputPassword(field=userRegistrationForm("passwords.password"), 'id ->"password", 
 'placeHolder -> "Password", 'pattern -> ".{7,}", 'title -> "7 character password at minimum",
 'required -> "true", '_label -> None, '_showConstraints -> true, '_errors -> true
)

@helper.inputPassword(field=userRegistrationForm("passwords.confirmPassword"), 'id ->"confirmPassword", 
'placeHolder -> "Confirm Password", '_label -> None, 'required -> "true", 
  '_showConstraints -> true
)
```

Comment: Put a `verifying` on the whole form and render the resulting issue in a global form errors section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is tied to the `passwords` field, and not either of the specific password fields, because that is the `mapping` you're calling `verifying` on. I'm not sure `helper` can help you here, because the error is tied to both fields.

You might have to deal with the `Form` object directly to do something with the error:

```
@userRegistrationForm.error("passwords").map { error =>
    error.message
}
```

Comment: in play 2.6 I use something like: @userRegistrationForm.error("passwords").map { error => @error.format }